# Ruby on Rails: Datatype foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following tables:

- Route(ID, Name) with Primary Key ID
- Stop(ID, Name) with Primary Key ID
- Mapping(Route_ID, Stop_ID)

The IDs in Route and Stop are of type BIGINT(20) in my Mysql-DB. The migration fails because using this:

```
class CreateMappings < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :mappings do |t|
    t.references :route, index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.references :stop, index: true, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
  end
end
```

Creates a table Mappings with route_id and stop_id but datatype INT(11). This is not compatible with the BIGINT(20). How can I fix this? Any ideas? The creation of the foreign keys fails.

**Error Messages**

This is a section of the output of `rake db:migrate --trace`:

> ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
>   ** Execute db:load_config
>   ** Execute db:migrate
>   == 20151227194101 CreateMappings: migrating ===================================
>   -- create_table(:mappings) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE
>   `mappings` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_1b9f715271` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`route_id`)   REFERENCES `routes` (`id`)

**When I try to execute the above SQL statement** (ALTER TABLE `mappings`...) using a MySql-Client, I get this error:

```
Failed to add the foreign key constaint. MIssing index for constraint 'fk_rails_1b9f715271' in the referenced table 'routes'.
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Added it to question.

Answer (score 8):

The `references` method takes a type option if you don't want the added column to be an integer, for example

```
t.references :route, type: :bigint, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this form?

```
class CreateMappings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :mappings do |t|
      t.references :route
      t.references :stop

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
  add_index(:mappings, :route)
  add_index(:mappings, :stop)
end
```

Comment: This does not help because the resulting data type of route will be a int and not bigint